# Gnuplot: Stop grid lines averaging over data in 3D plot

Tags: gnuplot

I've got a problem where I'm trying to make a plot of the Gibbs distribtion P = exp(-E/kT) in 3D (P vs E vs T) and put gridlines on it. I basically want to reproduce the one here http://arxiv.org/pdf/0803.0217.pdf at the top of page 3, but whenever I insert grid lines it averages over too much data and my plot just looks nearly flat (it doesn't have the sharp drop off near T->0 because it averages over too much data). Could anyone help me with this? Ty

Comment: So how does your non-working script look like?

Comment: check `help isosamples`

Comment: @bibi Isosamples won't fix this.  It isn't due to "averaging over too much data" as the OP suggested, but because the function has a singularity at T=0.

Answer (score 1):

If you try to graph that function with the default ranges, you will get an image that is nearly flat

```
# Arbitrary value for k.  
# I am not familiar with the physics here, so this may or may not be a reasonable value.
k = 2

P(E,T) = exp(-E/(k*T))
set xlab "Energy"
set ylab "Temperature"
splot P(x,y)
```

[image]

Notice that there are spikes at y=0 (y is temperature) and these spikes approach significant z values (3.5 x 10^21).  As the rest of the values never exceed 1 (being a probability), these spikes overpower everything else, so the graph appears flat elsewhere.  Adjusting the isosamples as suggested in comments will not help with this.

It isn't pretty, but we can see where this happens if we restrict the z range to a small interval with `set zrange[0:2]`.

[image]

The problem here is that the function tends to infinity for low negative temperatures with positive energies (and vice versa).  Low positive temperatures (with positive energies) do not have that problem (the function is undefined at T=0, but the limit as T approaches 0 from above is well defined to be 0 when E>0).  In context, it doesn't make sense for x or y to have negative values anyways.

To fix this, let's set the x and y ranges to be from 0 to 8 (matching your linked image), and turn up the isosamples (to give a finer mesh)

```
set xrange[0:8]
set yrange[0:8]
set isosamples 100
```

Now plotting with `splot P(x,y)` produces an image like the desired one

[image]

or with a slightly coarser mesh (`set isosamples 30`)

[image]

Notice, here that the line at Temperature=0 is missing.  This is again because the function is not defined there.  We can set a range very close to 0, but away from 0 to compensate for this (in the finer mesh gnuplot either didn't even attempt a line there, or the missing line was too dense for us to notice) with `set yrange[0.001:8]`.

[image]